# Graphene-python performance issues for large data sets

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

Currently using **graphene-python** with **graphene-django** (and **graphene-django-optimizer**).

After receiving a **GraphQL** query, the database query is successfully completed in a fraction of a second; however, graphene doesn't send a response for another 10+ seconds. If I increase the data being sent in the response, the response time increases linearly (triple the data = triple the response time).

The data being retrieved composed of nested objects, up to 7 layers deep, but with the optimized queries this doesn't impact the time taken to retrieve the data from the DB, so I'm assuming the delay has to do with graphene-python parsing the results into the **GraphQL** response.

I can't figure out how to profile the execution to determine what is taking so long -- running **cProfiler** on **Django** doesn't seem to be tracking the execution of graphene.

**SQL Query** response time was determined using the **graphene-django-debugger** middleware, results are shown below:

```
    "_debug": {
  "sql": [
    {
      "duration": 0.0016078948974609375,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT SYSDATETIME()"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0014908313751220703,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0014371871948242188,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.001291036605834961,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0013201236724853516,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0015559196472167969,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0016672611236572266,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0014820098876953125,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0014810562133789062,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.001667022705078125,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0014202594757080078,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0027959346771240234,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.002704143524169922,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    },
    {
      "duration": 0.0030939579010009766,
      "isSlow": false,
      "rawSql": "SELECT [redacted]"
    }
  ]
}
```

The screenshot below shows the server's corresponding response time for that same request:
[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTool Network post response times]

If anyone knows why graphene would take so long to create the response or could assist me with profiling the execution of graphene, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What is the graphql query?

Comment: Update question with resolvers and types. GraphQL is known to perform slow on deeper relations.

Comment: I would also suspect it being a resolver issue

Comment: How are you setting up the profiler? Could you try the WSGI profiling middleware from the Pallets Project https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/middleware/profiler/

Comment: Did you every figure out a solution, @techknowfile?

Comment: In case the library maintainers come across. Consider adding streaming to the deserializers. That way even a million length queryset will be handled gracefully.

Comment: Hi, how big is a JSON payload your endpoint generates? I experienced a big performance regression when the size of response got bigger than a couple of megabytes. I didn't diagnosed a problem on my side and it turned out that python eat out a lot of resources while the serializing process. i end up caching data and even creating a separated server instances that handles big requests.

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev I'm seeing this issue when the payload is ~1.5MB and contains ~10K objects.

Comment: @pdoherty926 that volume definetely should not take so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a better profiler like [Silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk), it will show you a breakdown based on queries Django fires to the DB, as well as a neat cProfiler overview. I would suspect an issue in extraneous DB calls. Graphene tends to make Django do a lot of per-field calls while constructing the response and they might not be showing up in the debugger response.

Without more information on the setup - models, resolvers and graphql queries - it's very hard to judge.

Edit: it's now clear from the question that the DB is not an issue

Comment: It is not DB related. Graphene takes an unusual amount of time serializing deeply nested querysets.

Comment: that was not evident from the question when posted, now it is, capturing more of the stack with more than just cprofiler is still a solid suggestion, graphene-django-debugger as per the question is ofc another good choice to check db call only

Comment: Since you have realized that, I would suggest more edit to your answer than what you have done so far.